After opening in a local window, it displays blank content
Phenomenon
Display blank after running
Description
I thought the program code was written incorrectly, so I used minimal functionality to reproduce the code, but the problem still occurred.
Reproduce code
from nicegui import ui
ui.label("page with custom title")
ui.run(native=True, window_size=(400, 300), fullscreen=False)

System environment
python 3.11.9 64-bit, nicegui 2.5.0

maybe try again after installing pywebview ? the code prompts me Native mode is not supported in this configuration. Please run "pip install pywebview" to use it. but the ui.label appears with "page with custom title" after installing pywebview.

thanks, after upgrading pywebview, it runs normally. Previously, there was no prompt saying 'Please run' pip install pywebview 'to use it, so I couldn't find the problem
